# Executing consecutive processes with execl()

Tags: c++, unix, process

I have what is hopefully a simple question. I'd like to execute three programs called "brute_seq", "brute_pth" and "brute_omp" consecutively; basically execute "brute_seq", wait until it's finished, then execute "brute_pth" and same thing for "brute_omp".

I've tried doing this several different ways and so far, the best solution I've come up with is this, although it's not quite what I need.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    if(fork() == 0)
        execl("brute_seq", (const char*)NULL, (char*)NULL);

    if(fork() == 0)
        execl("brute_pth", (const char*)NULL, (char*)NULL);

    if(fork() == 0)
        execl("brute_omp", (const char*)NULL, (char*)NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, the forked process will run the execl() command, which in turn will replace the forked process with the called process - this insures that my forked process terminates when the called process ends.

I have two problems with this implementation:

1. The processes do not execute sequentially, but in parallel, which I don't want.
2. Once they're all done executing, my terminal blocks in a similar way that it would block when encountering a deadlock due to poor synchronization, except worse, because I can't CTRL-Z out of it; I have to exit from the terminal and open it again.

Any ideas?

---

Thanks to Joachim's helpful tip, here's the working code that does exactly what I want:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t child_pid;
    int status;

    if((child_pid = fork()) == 0)
        execl("brute_seq", (const char*)NULL, (char*)NULL);
    else
    {
        waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
        if((child_pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            execl("brute_pth", (const char*)NULL, (char*)NULL);
        }
        waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
        execl("brute_omp", (const char*)NULL, (char*)NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) on the processes to finish. It also have the side-effect of cleaning up your child zombie processes after they finish.

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you very much! I'll post the working code in the original comment.